# php fetch_object inheritance

Tags: php, mysql, inheritance

I have class:

```
class item{ 
  public id='';
  public name='';
}
```

inside this class i want to have a function that fills up class with values from mysql query
like this:

```
 $result_item = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT *
            FROM items 
            WHERE item_id=".$item_id." 
            LIMIT 1");
 $res = $result_item->fetch_object(SalesOrderItem);
 $this = $res;
```

this code doesnt work, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: `SalesOrderItem` is not `item`. Also: You missed the quotes

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this in Z:\home\krumaninside\www\ordering\includes\classes\sales_order_item.class.php on line 39

Comment: @AnKing Why would you be trying to assign a value to `$this`? That make no sense.

Comment: @Mike Brant Because i want to fill class with the result of mysql call

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the documentation around the mysqli::fetch_object.

Your class name needs to be specified as a string like so:

```
$result_item->fetch_object('SalesOrderItem'); // or 'item' your question is inconsistent here
```

You also may need to pass some values to the constructor to help you along.  I would strongly recommend reading through the user notes on the documentation page - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php for some better examples of usage than given in the main documentation itself.

The fatal error you mention in your comments is because you can't change `$this`.  That is an internal reference to the current object instance.  Trying to change it make no sense.

If you intent is you have an object class that is, in essence, its own object relational mapper (ORM). To where it makes a call to the database, populates properties from records and somehow mutates itself into another class, this is not really possible.  What you probably need to look to do is utilize a factory pattern of sorts to have a class that does nothing but instantiate classes of given type using the ORM approach.

So maybe usage would be like this:

```
// The class with MySQLi logic could be called something like MysqlObjectfactory
// It could take input like an instantiated mysqli object, DB table name, 
// the class name you are trying to map to, and the id for the specific item in the class you are looking for
// it would use the logic noted above to generate an object with the specifications given
// and return it to the caller
$object = MysqliObjectFactory::getObject($mysqli, $db_table, $class_name, $id);
```

The other thought that jump to my mind is: why reinvent the wheel? It sounds like what you are looking for is an object relational mapper.  There are several of these for PHP that are really widely used: Doctrine, Propel, PHP Active Record, etc.  You might check these out as they will give you a lot more functionalitu/flexibility than trying to do this with `mysqli::fetch_object()` where the mapping depends on the database field (or provided alias in SQL) exactly matching the class property names (that is without having to do mapping in class constructor).

Comment: comes up with fatal error that i've specified before

Comment: Is there a wat to just copy the properties out of mysql result into the main class?

Comment: @Anking I think you are thinking about this the wrong way. The class which is calling the mysql DB should probably not be the same class as the object you are trying to create. I updated my answer above with some more thoughts on a better approach.